# Could no open /dev/vmmon: no such file or directory

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-fusion

The following error occurred when resuming the windows 10 VM on Mac OS. 
[image]

According to some posts the module is for linux guest OS not Windows Guests

Reinstalling the VMWare fusion did not solve the problem. Load a previous snapshot either.

VMWare Fusion version is 8.5.10, the latest 8 version.

Comment: FYI, that module is a *host* driver and doesn't have anything to do with the guest.

Comment: was running on a mac, makes sense

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the last Mac OS update was somehow failing.

I try a reboot and and find that the last Mac OS update was still in progress and failing. The boot failed to load package OSInstall.pkmg. I reboot again and choose to boot from main drive instead the update and the problem was solved. 
Yet, 2 odd things were on the system after fix it. The Mac OS version was the latest version(10.13.3) and backup disk was damaged.